# Safest place for small business to store passwords

Tags: passwords, password-management

Where is the safest place for a small business to store its passwords for servers, web domain credentials, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

If you have a small number of people and want to save some money, I would say a number of KeePass databases shared somehow (network share, google drive, etc), and backed up in several ways. The only 'hurdle' is that **when someone leaves the company you would need to cycle all the passwords of the DBs the person had access to**, as they could walk away with a copy of the DB.

Also free, you also have [PassBolt](https://www.passbolt.com/), which you can install on premise and is open source. The extra trouble with this, is that the server where you are running PassBolt has to be hardened to the core. If you can afford it, I would recommend getting the paid version as it offers 2FA (cycling password still applies).

Also on the entry level (money wise) the more advanced offerings of companies like LastPass or 1Pass that allow sharing credentials between teams. Personally, I don't really trust them, and the thing about cycling password still applies again.

If you have a big pile of money, there are are some onpremise platforms such as CyberArk Enterprise Password Vault that also report who and when someone requested a password. I haven't seen any of these platforms being opensource, and you can see which passwords in particular need to be cycled rather than everything.

Comment: Thank you for those suggestions. What do you think of password storage on something like hardback notepad which is then locked away or taken off-site?

Comment: That is quite good but I can see 2 drawbacks: "usability" (do you need to bring that notepad from the safe 40 times a day?) and backups. In my eyes this might be useful and very secure if you have a very small number of credentials which are not used often.